# Extend ext4 partition with unallocated but with /boot in the middle

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have my computer with dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 and now I want to move it to have a single-boot with Ubuntu.
So, using GParted  I unallocated the windows partition and I want to extend my Ubuntu partition, but here is my problem, I have in the middle a partition with "File System" as "ext4 /boot" and I can't move it or even unallocate.

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFfl9.png)

Do I have any option to extend my Ubuntu?
I don't want to lose my data on Ubuntu, so If I have to override my current installation, I prefer to just set that partition as "ext4" and use it as a secondary disk.

Comment: If you have backups then data loss is a moot point. And considering you need to move 2 partitions, each operation being risky by itself, you really should have backups.

Comment: Boot from a Live USB (or your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode) - one cannot edit the partition table for the disk while ANY of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Comment: Little lock icons means partitions are mounted. You have to work with unmounted partitions. Best to just use live installer with gparted or a gparted ISO as live system. You can create an ext4 partition and use it as a data partition for some or most of data now in /home, but keeping /home inside / (root). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk